# Unexpected javascript output

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a lot of table rows dynamically generated which generally take the form of the following

```
<td class="seatClass" >
    <label for="C" class="label-format" >
        <span > C0</span >
    </label >
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "C" name = "seats[US57][]" style = "display: inline-block;" value = "C"  class="terminalCheckbox" onchange = "parentNode.querySelector('span').classList.toggle('green');" />
</td>
```

Basically, my code displays a lot of labels and checkboxes in different rows. If X represents the checkbox, you can imagine something like this

```
LX IX DX JX
OX PX IX DX 
BX AX WX QX
```

Now sometimes these rows contain the same labels for instance I appears in both the first and second rows and the code for the two will almost be identical (because the values for their id's and names are dynamic).

Anyways, I am facing a weird problem.  If you check a checkbox, I wanted its associated letter to turn green, hence the bit of javascript I added.  This works fine.  However, my problem is say I click on the letter I on the second row (not the checkbox).  If I do this, the checkbox for the I in the first row gets checked and the I in the first row turns green.  So checking a checkbox things work fine, but if I click a letter things are messed up.

Is there any reason looking at my code as to why this is happening?  I have no other javascript on this, I can only think it is because labels and checkboxes are being replicated on other rows, but it still kind of confuses me as to why this would happen.

Thanks

Comment: Are the IDs being duplicated for entries with the same label?  If so, the <label> elements for all checkboxes with the same ID will refer to the first such checkbox via their 'for' attributes.

Comment: That now makes sense.  Made me look into something and have now sorted it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that IDs *have* to be unique.

Instead of specifying the `for` attribute, wrap the input with the label. This makes it unnecessary to know the exact id of the nested control.

```css
.green{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
<td class="seatClass" >
    <label class="label-format" >
        <span > C0</span >
   
    <input type="checkbox"  name="seats[US57][]" style="display: inline-block;" value="C"  class="terminalCheckbox" onchange="parentNode.classList.toggle('green');" />
       </label >
</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="seatClass" >
    <label class="label-format" >
        <span > C0</span >
   <!-- note: change the onchange javascript to match the new layout.
       The label will now be the parent of the input. -->
    <input type="checkbox"  name="seats[US57][]" style="display: inline-block;" value="C"  class="terminalCheckbox" onchange="parentNode.classList.toggle('green');" />

       </label >
</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```